# ODATA with keywords

Tags: 2013, odata

I'm new in Tridion 2013 and I would like to use ODATA. 
If I have a keywords with a Metadata Schema where we add some information related with the keyword. 
Can I insert in ODATA the information? (not just the title, description and key. The information in the metadata schema too)

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Tridion oData web service is used to query content, not to insert content in the CMS. If I understand correctly your question, you would like to be able to retrieve the Keyword Metadata by querying the oData web service.

This is possible by querying the CustomMetas oData entity with for example this C# Expression query in Linqpad http://www.linqpad.net/ :

```
from x in CustomMetas
where x.PublicationId==27 && x.ItemId==3326
select x
```

In this example 3326 is the Keyword ID.

Corresponding RESTful URL query:
`http://yoururl.yourdomain/odata.svc/CustomMetas()?$filter=PublicationId eq 27 and ItemId eq 3326`

[image: Linqpad Tridion oData Query]

You need to Publish the Category containing your keywords to be able to find them via oData.
Here is my keyword in Tridion:

[image: Tridion Keyword with Metadata]